# Multiple foreach loop containers in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am working on a package which requires multiple data flow task within multiple foreach loop containers. The issue arises when i try and run the whole package. The first data flow task within the first for each loop container executes successfully but the flow doesn't enter the other for each loop containers. the initial package looks like :

*Initial Package*

[image: Initial Package(Before execution)]

*Package after execution*

[image: Package after execution]

I want to know what changes are required to make the data flow task within the other containers to execute.(All variables have a package scope). For each loop containers are running successfully when kept in different packages.

Comment: can you add a snapshot of the `foreach loop container` settings?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it is entering into the other for loops as well, however it is not finding right set of Files to process, please check your for collection of objects.
Also you have expressions in foreach loops, so check whether they are evaluating correctly.

i.e it may have *.txt, but you don't have any such files in the folder. so only foreach loop is executing but not the data flow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it should still go to the the data flow task within the other container and give me an error or information that it is trying to read a file or file not found message. Also the same things work if i execute each container in a different package. (I checked the location of files and i have multiple files of the specified format).

Comment: When there are no files it will not give any error, it will just skip. So after your first foreach loop, you can put a script and check what is your File collection expression value in a message box and see whether it has any matching files for that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check to see if anything that is being done in the first for loop is causing the expressions in the other for loops to evaluate incorrectly.

Comment: I checked all the expressions using a script task there value remains according to the requirement but still it is not executing the data flow task in the other foreach loops.

Comment: Have you tried doing a sample run of the entire process with a test file (or other object) without the foreach loops, just to see if the process completes fine without them?

Answer (score -1):

string[] arr = new string[] { "https://sim.oecd.org/Export.ashx?lang=En&ds=TFI&d1c=hinoecd&d2c=atg&d2cc=bp",
                "https://sim.oecd.org/Export.ashx?lang=En&ds=TFI&d1c=hinoecd&d2c=bhs&d2cc=bp",
                "https://sim.oecd.org/Export.ashx?lang=En&ds=TFI&d1c=hinoecd&d2c=bhr&d2cc=bp" };
                try
            {
                string fileName = Dts.Variables["User::filename"].Value.ToString(), myWebString = null, myLocalPath = null;
                WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
                foreach (string myURI in arr)
                {
                    myWebString = myURI + fileName;
                    myLocalPath = "c:\sql\" + fileName;
                    myWebClient.DownloadFile(myWebString, myLocalPath);
                }
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireError(18, "The process failed", ex.ToString(), "", 0);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }
my code is working fine but only one url how to take different url to download files how can i d

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the question